# Change the word Shipping to Delivery in Woocommerce cart and checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

Im using woocommerce and I want to change the "Shipping" word to "Delivery". Tried code in the functions.php folder but nothing seems to work.

My [site](http://www.piquantrestaurant.co.uk/) is a restaurant and it just looks weird to say "shipping" food.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't get notified when you make a comment as an answer… Instead at the bottom of my answer, there is a comment zone for that. Now your problem is that you have never add any customizations to your function.php file and you got an error because of the last closing tag `? >` that you added after my code in your theme's function.php… So remove it and save it. Then you can give me some feed back on my answer comment area. My code is tested and works just fine.

Comment: As you are a new user you should [take the quick tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) that will explain you in 30 seconds how StackOverFlow works basically. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I went into my hosting page and file manager and opened up functions.php. I then copied this text and pasted into the file after the '< ? php' code and at the bottom I placed the '? >' symbol. When i load my page the code apears at the top and nothing has changed. It seems to cause an error. Any thoughts?? Thanks again.

Also i live in the uk so currency may be different?? £ instead of $

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will change the word "Shipping" to "Delivery" in cart and checkout pages:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_shipping_package_name', 'change_shipping_text_to_delivery', 20, 3 );
function change_shipping_text_to_delivery( $sprintf, $i, $package ) {
    $sprintf = sprintf( _nx( 'Delivery', 'Delivery %d', ( $i + 1 ), 'delivery packages', 'woocommerce' ), ( $i + 1 ) );
    return $sprintf;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

You will get something like this in cart and checkout pages:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I went into my hosting page and file manager and opened up functions.php. I then copied this text and pasted into the file after the '< ? php' code and at the bottom I placed the '? >' symbol. When i load my page the code apears at the top and nothing has changed. It seems to cause an error. Any thoughts?? Thanks again.

Also i live in the uk so currency may be different?? £ instead of $

Comment: This is what it said when i published: Don't Panic

The code snippet you are trying to save produced a fatal error on line 4:
syntax error, unexpected 'return' (T_RETURN)

The previous version of the snippet is unchanged, and the rest of this site should be functioning normally as before.

Please use the back button in your browser to return to the previous page and try to fix the code error. If you prefer, you can close this page and discard the changes you just made. No changes will be made to this site.

Comment: also do you run the snippet once, in admin, front end, or everywhere

Comment: @MarkRoberts My fault sorry, there was a missing ";" so I have updated the code and It should work now. Try it again. Thanks you.

Comment: Thank you my friend i appreciate that. I worked !! yay.

Comment: Another question. do you have a code for the basket page to do the same thing? Thanks Mark.

Comment: @MarkRoberts It works on cart and on checkout pages. If you have other questions, you should ask a new question. Thanks.